# need to add a class to an element

Tags: javascript, css

here's my code:

```
<body>
<header>
<h1>Html quiz</h1>
</header>
<article>
<h2>What color is this?&nbsp;&nbsp; #00ff00

<ul>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="color1" id="red" />&nbsp;&nbsp;red
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="color1" id="green" />&nbsp;&nbsp;green
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="color1" id="blue" />&nbsp;&nbsp;blue
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="color1" id="teal" />&nbsp;&nbsp;teal
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="fsubmit()" />
    </li>
</ul>
</article>
<div id="result"> </div>
<script>
function fsubmit() {
var answer = document.getElementById("green");
var result = document.getElementById("result");
if(answer.checked == true) {result.innerHTML="correct!";} else {result.class="red";  result.innerHTML="wrong";}
}
</script>
</body>
```

It's the first bit of code **result.class="red"** does nothing and the debugging console on chrome doesn't indicate a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using setAttribute on the result:

```
result.setAttribute("class","red");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `result.className = 'red';`, but you can also use `result.classList.add('red');`. The `.classList.add(str)` way is usually easier if you need to add a class in general, and don't want to check if the class is already in the list of classes.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `className`

```
result.className = "red"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing h2 tag. It should be:

```
<h2><!-- Content --></h2>
```

Comment: This is not that big of an issue with HTML.

Comment: it doesn't cause the javascript issue, however.

Comment: I think it's good form to close any tags that have content though html5 allows one to skip closing tags on many elements.  In this case it was an oversite on my part.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like:

```
result.className = 'red';
```

In pure JavaScript you should use `className` to deal with classes. jQuery has an abstraction called `addClass` for it.

Comment: sorry, that's a typo, I meant `addClass`.